# how to create temp tables dynamically from dataframe column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Me using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java8.
I have a requirement for which I need to createdTempTable table whose data on which  it is group by "country_id".

to make my spark parallel , I need to create a tempTable for each country.
i.e. want to create a tempTable for each "country_id" dynamically.

how to do this , any advice please.

Answer (score 2):

```
{      package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DynamicTempTable extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Mapper")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class Country(
                     ID: Int,
                     name: String
                    )

  val countryDF = Seq(
    Country(1, "c1"),
    Country(2, "c2"),
    Country(3, "c3"),
    Country(4, "c4"),
    Country(5, "c5"),
    Country(6, "c6"),
    Country(7, "c7"),
    Country(8, "c8"),
    Country(9, "c9"),
    Country(10, "c10")
  ).toDF()

  val listCountries = countryDF.select('ID).distinct().rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
  println(s"list countries: $listCountries")

  listCountries.foreach(i => {
    countryDF.filter('ID.equalTo(i)).createTempView(s"tmp_table_country_$i")
  })
// or parallel
listCountries.par.foreach(i => {
countryDF.filter('ID.equalTo(i)).createTempView(s"tmp_table_country_$i") })
}
```

}

Comment: collect I used to get a list of countries.

>> and need to use it in further logic after group by...- you can save DataFrame to table(s) database. Then (after done task) use in other tasks

Comment: pls, see my example 2.  collect get countries list (example 1) or country directory (example 2) to the driver. we not collect country data after group by to the driver. if you have questions write. thx. I can try to do a full task if you show the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a country directory

```
{    package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}

object DynamicTempTable extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Mapper")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class Country(
                     ID: Int,
                     name: String
                    )

  case class CountryData(
                      ID: Int,
                      capital: String,
                      population: Long
                    )

  case class CountryTable(
                      ID: Int,
                      name: String,
                      nameTable: String
                    )

  val countryDF = Seq(
    Country(1, "c1"),
    Country(2, "c2"),
    Country(3, "c3"),
    Country(4, "c4"),
    Country(5, "c5"),
    Country(6, "c6"),
    Country(7, "c7"),
    Country(8, "c8"),
    Country(9, "c9"),
    Country(10, "c10")
  ).toDF()


  val countryData = Seq(
    CountryData(1, "cp1", 11),
    CountryData(2, "cp2", 22),
    CountryData(3, "cp3", 33),
    CountryData(4, "cp4", 44),
    CountryData(5, "cp5", 55),
    CountryData(6, "cp6", 66),
    CountryData(7, "cp7", 77),
    CountryData(8, "cp8", 88),
    CountryData(9, "cp9", 99),
    CountryData(10, "cp10", 1010)
  ).toDF()

  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  var tableToCountry = new ListBuffer[CountryTable]()

  countryDF.collect().foreach(i => {

    val nameTempTable = s"${i.getAs[String]("name")}_temp_table"
    val countryId = i.getAs[Int]("ID")
    val countryName = i.getAs[String]("name")

    countryData.filter('ID.equalTo(countryId)).createOrReplaceTempView(nameTempTable)

    tableToCountry += CountryTable(countryId, countryName, nameTempTable)

  })

  val tcDF = tableToCountry.toDF()
  tcDF.show(false)
//  +---+----+--------------+
//  |ID |name|nameTable     |
//  +---+----+--------------+
//  |1  |c1  |c1_temp_table |
//  |2  |c2  |c2_temp_table |
//  |3  |c3  |c3_temp_table |
//  |4  |c4  |c4_temp_table |
//  |5  |c5  |c5_temp_table |
//  |6  |c6  |c6_temp_table |
//  |7  |c7  |c7_temp_table |
//  |8  |c8  |c8_temp_table |
//  |9  |c9  |c9_temp_table |
//  |10 |c10 |c10_temp_table|
//  +---+----+--------------+

  tcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("table_to_country")

  spark.table("table_to_country").show(false)
//  +---+----+--------------+
//  |ID |name|nameTable     |
//  +---+----+--------------+
//  |1  |c1  |c1_temp_table |
//  |2  |c2  |c2_temp_table |
//  |3  |c3  |c3_temp_table |
//  |4  |c4  |c4_temp_table |
//  |5  |c5  |c5_temp_table |
//  |6  |c6  |c6_temp_table |
//  |7  |c7  |c7_temp_table |
//  |8  |c8  |c8_temp_table |
//  |9  |c9  |c9_temp_table |
//  |10 |c10 |c10_temp_table|
//  +---+----+--------------+


  println(s"~~~~> check result for table ${tcDF.select('nameTable).take(1)(0).mkString}")
  spark.table(tcDF.select('nameTable).take(1)(0).mkString).show(false)

//  ~~~~> check result for table c1_temp_table
//  +---+-------+----------+
//  |ID |capital|population|
//  +---+-------+----------+
//  |1  |cp1    |11        |
//  +---+-------+----------+


}
```

}